# Java DatagramPacket object returning IPV6 address but require IPv4

Tags: java, android, udp, ipv6, ipv4

I am using a DatagramPacket object named "packet" to receive packets from the network and using the packet object to get the IP address of the sender (That is, using packet.getAddress() ). However, it returns an IPv6 address representing the sender while I want an IPv4 address. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 and IPv6 are separate protocols. If you get an IPv6 address then you received a packet over IPv6, so that is the address you'll see. IPv6 is being deployed all over the world, so your software will have to deal with it. There is no relation between IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses, so if you see an IPv6 address then that is all you are going to get.

The only exception is when receiving IPv4 packets over an IPv6 socket. In that case you will see an IPv6 address that starts with `::ffff:`. What follows after that is the IPv4 address. In this case you are not really communicating over IPv6, so you can see IPv4 addresses.